# suggestions for a ~20cm 2 way wireless communication between arduino like devices

Tags: rf, communication

I am trying to build a system where, when and only when someone is within close proximity, about 20 cm or so, two arduino like devices can communicate wirelessly.

I want to be able to communicate data from the device back to the human, and data from the human to the device, probably with some kind of antenna mounted in the back of a glove.

I was looking into nfc, but it appears that nfc is one way.

What are your suggestions?

For clarification, I would like to add that there would be many devices that the user may or may not choose to use.

Comment: While it may or may not be otherwise appropriate to your application, your belief that nfc is one way is mistaken.

Comment: Bluetooth. Depending on your budget and your throughput.

Comment: @Chirs Stratton, for my information, would you mind directing me to some examples of 2 way nfc?

Comment: @Reinderien, If I ran with bluetooth, is there an easy enough way to take very little time while connecting to devices? My project involves the possibility and necessity to quickly change what is being actively communicated. Do most modules support multiple connections? Is there a way to quicken connection time? My only experience with bluetooth is with my phone, I don't think it can connect to multiple devices at once.

Comment: Multiple connections? That doesn't sound like the use case you described. Perhaps you should edit your question.

Comment: @Reinderien, your right, thats not what I described, but my expierence with bluetooth is that it takes a while to connect, I think I could accommodate this by connecting to multiple devices, and detecting when the user wanted to use the device with a pushbutton or something similar.

As opposed to connecting to the nearest device (probably the one the user is holding) and communicating very quickly. Again, I dont know what is possible, Im just trying to work with what is possible.

Comment: `nfc peer-to-peer`

Comment: You need to add some numbers to the question for (a) how quickly communications has to start upon presence detect. (b) how long the two way transaction processing will last and (c) how much data is transferred. Without these numbers it is pointless to talk about any types of interfaces that may be used.

Comment: this page https://www.adafruit.com/product/789 ... says this `While the controller has many capabilities, our Arduino library currently only supports reading/writing tags, and does not support phone-to-shield communication, tag emulation (which requires an external 'secure element' only available from NXP) or other more advanced features at this time.`

Comment: what kind of data are you wanting to transfer? ... is it fixed? .... you could use two NFC modules and two RFID tags .... human walks up ... device reads human's RFID tag .... device programs device's RFID tag .... human's NFC module reads device's RFID tag ... device could also program human's RFID tag and vice-versa

Comment: @jsotola - using a tag as an intermediary is quite roundabout and doesn't really seem like a fit for this.  The limitation you describe is one of an particular Arduino library, not of the technology itself, even when used with an Arduino.  Try reading the actual NFC chip data sheets.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, that is most likely, it was just an idea to circumvent the use of the "secure element", which appears to be required for a peer-to-peer connection .... i could very well be wrong about the "secure element"

Comment: You are wrong about the secure element.

Answer (score 1):

The most economical two way general communication often used for short path <1m  uses one or more optical transceivers such as IRDA and IRDA2 depending on bandwidth and nearby reflections or directional wide angle coverage.

https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/sensors-transducers/irda-transceiver-modules/538?k=IRDA&stock=1

Comment: +1 for exactly what I was about to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Use some fast square wave edges, and let the displacement currents between 2 plates provide the data link. To avoid errors, have some pseudo-random patterns and have the receiver test the patterns of UP and DOWN spikes to validate the just-sent baud.